# Django Model Form Many to Many field is not displaying value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a many to many field and a foreign key field on a model form. It appears to be making the right query but the result are Objects and not the values of the object.

Do I need to overwrite the queryset using a VALUES_LIST method?

**forms.py**

```
    class Meta:
    model = AccountParameters
    fields =['acctFilterName', 'excludeClassification', 'tradingCash',]
    #exclude = ['acctFilterName']
    labels = {
        'acctFilterName': _('Account Filters:'),
        'excludeClassification': _('Exclude Classifications: '),
        'tradingCash':_('Remove accounts whose trading cash < % of AUM: ')
    }
```

**models.py**

```
class AccountParameters(models.Model):
acctFilterName = models.ForeignKey(AccountFilters)
excludeClassification = models.ManyToManyField(ClassificationNames)
tradingCash = models.FloatField()
```

[image: Screenshot of multiselect]

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a method to represent your object with a string :

If you are using python 2, use `__unicode__` and on python 3 use : `__str__` .

E.g (with python 2) :

```python
class AccountFilters(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # other attributes

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class AccountParameters(models.Model):
    acctFilterName = models.ForeignKey(AccountFilters)
    excludeClassification = models.ManyToManyField(ClassificationNames)
    tradingCash = models.FloatField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.acctFilterName.name
```

E.g (with python 3) :

```python
class AccountFilters(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # other attributes

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AccountParameters(models.Model):
    acctFilterName = models.ForeignKey(AccountFilters)
    excludeClassification = models.ManyToManyField(ClassificationNames)
    tradingCash = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.acctFilterName.name
```